# CQ5 component with class flex-wrap in edit mode

Tags: flexbox, aem

[I set div with style flex-wrap: wrap, but in edit mode, the two parsys don't side by side, but I modify wrap to nowrap, them display side by side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqW7n.png)

[But when I add this style in html page, the style is work, but it doesn't work as expected, then I modify nowrap to wrap, it doesn't work as the first image, finally, I modify wrap to nowrap again, then it works as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiazA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the containers to

```
display: inline-block;
```

I used this approach when I needed to make a 2-column display where each column contained a parsys, and that sounds similar to what you want to do.